# How do we instruct the Azure Event Grid Webhook subscription request to skip Server Certificate validation?

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I am trying to register an event grid webhook subscription towards a traffic manager endpoint. Since the CN of the certificate used in our dev/int environment does not match the hostname, I want to disable the cert validation (as a temporary measure) and register the webhook. I used the advanced editor in azure portal and below payload to register the webhook. But getting an error message which says "HTTP POST failed with response code Unknown". I know that the issue is related to cert validation because, if I put another SSL URL, the registration is going through.

[image]

Shouldn't outbound__webhook__skipServerCertValidation parameter help here?

```
{
    "Env": [
        "outbound__webhook__httpsOnly=false",
        "outbound__webhook__skipServerCertValidation=true",
        "outbound__webhook__allowUnknownCA=true"
    ],
    "name": "PaginatedUserQueryEventProcessor",
    "properties": {
        "topic": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/mtntprUserQueryTopic",
        "destination": {
            "endpointType": "WebHook",
            "properties": {
                "endpointUrl": "https://myendpoint.trafficmanager.net/v1.0/notificationprocessor/policy-assignment-update",
                "maxEventsPerBatch": 1,
                "preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes": 64
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "advancedFilters": []
        },
        "labels": [],
        "eventDeliverySchema": "EventGridSchema"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else is looking for a solution to this problem I was able to workaround the cert validation issue by updating the Subject Alternative Name of my certificate to have the hostname.

Comment: Hi , Can you please elaborate your answer.  I am getting exactly same error. I am using azure event gird trigger function as webhook.(which expects the client certificate)